# Programmatically Load Texture in Image and Set Border to the Image Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, border

I am developing a endless game, and want to take a Snapshot when the player Dies. I've almost done that using Texture2D. i have done Load Texture in image programmatically. but want to set border to the image. How can i do that.? how can i set border to that image at Run-time.?

This Code For Load Texture To the Image at Run-time when my player Dies.

```
void LoadImage(){

    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (Application.dataPath +"/GameOverScreenShot" + "/BirdDiedScreenShot.png");
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (900, 900, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
    texture.LoadImage (bytes);
    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, 700, 380), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
    imgObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image> ().sprite = sprite;


}
```

i want to Set Border to that image at Run-time. any one can help i really appreciate. thanks in Advance.

Comment: not easy, one way is to use a sort of rendertexture camera

Comment: Can u tel me how?? give any Example, Link, Video, Anything. i don't know about rendertexture

Comment: what do you mean when you say you wan to set the border to the image? You want to apply a vignette to the snapshot?

Comment: i mean that i take a snapshot when my player dies and set into UnityEngine.UI.Image but also want to set Border to that image at run-time.

Comment: no @fafase i don't want to apply vignette to the snapshot. just want to set border to the snapshot runtime.

Comment: Set border as to what? I got the part where you say you want to set border? I just don't understand what setting border of a Sprite means. The size? Next to another image?

Comment: no not Size @fafase just simple to understand that when i take the snapshot when player dies.  it display in one UI Image in my UI Panel. and i want to display snapshot with border. my question is how to set Border in UI Image at Run-time ????

Answer (score -1):

Do this after you load the image into the Texture2D variable and this will change the border of the image to whatever color you want.

```
 //color should be a variable that holds the color of the border you want.

for (int i = 0; i< texture.width; i++){
    texture.SetPixel(i, 0, color); //top border
    texture.SetPixel(i, texture.height - 1, color); //bottom border
}

for (int j = 0; j < texture.height; j++){
    texture.SetPixel(0, j, color); // left border
    texture.SetPixel(texture.width - 1, j, color); //right border   
}
texture.Apply();
```

This will replace any pixels on the edge of your original image so if you need those edge pixels you will need to look for another solution. Also, texture.Apply takes a while to run so if you need to constantly apply this border you may experience slowdown but you mentioned it is only when the player dies so this should not be an issue.